# XML Schema con Atributos fixed y default

Tags: xml, atributos, xsd

estoy probando con un XML Schema los atributos fixed y default. Lo que entiendo es que con el Fixed, el atributo en cuestión siempre llevará el valor que se indique, y con el Default, en caso de que en el XML no lleve asignado un valor, se asigna el valor por defecto.

El codigo XML es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fichas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="marcadores.xsd">
   <ficha numero="1">
      <nombre>Ana Sanz Tin</nombre>
      <edad>22</edad>
   </ficha>
   <ficha>
      <nombre>Iker Rubio Mol</nombre>
      <edad>23</edad>
   </ficha>
</fichas>
```

Y el código XSD es este:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="fichas">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ficha" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="edad" type="xs:integer"/>
             </xs:sequence>
             <xs:attribute name="numero" type="xs:integer"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

La salida en el navegador es esta:

```
<ficha numero="1">
<nombre>Ana Sanz Tin</nombre>
<edad>22</edad>
</ficha>
<ficha>
<nombre>Iker Rubio Mol</nombre>
<edad>23</edad>
</ficha>
</fichas>
```

El caso es que al abrir el XML con un navegador, el atributo numero en la segunda etiqueta ficha no aparece (ni con default, ni con fixed)
¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

En el XSD es necesario que en el elemento especifiques el atributo default o fixed para que pueda realizar  la función indicada.

Por ejemplo:

<xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string **default**="sin especificar"/>

Si no se introduce un nombre se asumirá "sin especificar" (el elemento nombre aparece vacío en el XML) y si se introduce se asumirá el nombre indicado en el XML.

<xs:element name="edad" type="xs:integer" **fixed**="0"/>

En este caso si la edad aparece en el XML solamente podrá ser 0 y en caso de aparecer como elemento vacío se asumirá el valor fijo 0.

Al abrir el XML con el navegador no lo vas a ver reflejado, eso sí ocurre con un DTD interno, pero si el DTD es externo tampoco aparece reflejado.

En el caso de XSD, el fichero con el esquema siempre es independiente, por eso el navegador no lo muestra.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Me queda claro aunque me surge otra duda a raíz de tu respuesta: ¿Si en el Xml no aparecen los valores definidos para fixed o default, en caso de cargar en una web la info del Xml mediante DOM, estos datos (default/fixed) se cargarian?

Comment: Sí realizamos el proceso de validación contra el Schema al cargarlos sí.